# PulseAudio problems

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, startup-applications

I have been working on the OS (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS) for a year more or less, and everything worked perfectly, but since few days audio icon disappeared, and I was no able to manage any audio setting, so I reinstalled PulseAudio (Alsamixer too), and everything worked again, but I had to add to the startup applications the `pulseaudio` command but it is not shown in the bar.

What can I do to append the icon to the bar?

Answer (score 1):

When you say bar, do you mean the dock that is by default on the left side of the screen? If so, you can click on the search icon, search for pulse audio, then click on the icon and drag it to the dock.

Comment: My bad, I meant the bar on the top, the one which has the hour, date, sound (not in my case), etc.